# What happens when you do a linear regression with duplicate response variables?

Tags: regression, medicine

Does doing linear regression on data with duplicate response variable given different independent variables even make sense? I was asked to fit a linear regression to data and the first thing I noticed was that the response variables had 3 duplicates, when the set of independent variables paired with each response variable are totally unique.

It's a bit confusing but the predictor values for the regression are B-spline coefficients from fitting a model to some label. The B-spline is fit to checking if someone has a disease given vitality ratings. The B-spline coefficients are the predictors for the linear regression and how much medication is y. The multiple ys I am getting are 0, so I'm assuming that it's cause people who don't have the disease shouldn't be taking any medication, which is why there are duplicates.

Does it make sense to do a linear regression on a problem like this? What insights about the data can be gained by doing so?

Comment: You need to give more details for this to be answerable! Why are there duplicates?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen added it to the question. I was worried it'd make the question more confusing but maybe I'm wrong.