# Why does linear regression on a duplicated set of data in R not match up to its theoretical standard errors?

Tags: regression

In the post:

[What happens when you do a linear regression with duplicate response variables?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/491737/what-happens-when-you-do-a-linear-regression-with-duplicate-response-variables)

it says that if we replicated data twice, the standard errors should be reduced by a factor of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. I have some sample data from the `cars` package I ran two regressions on, one with the original set, the other with the duplicated set.

```
> library(datasets)
> data(cars)
> mod1 = lm(dist ~ speed, data = cars)
> summary(mod1)
> mod2 = lm(rep(dist,2) ~ rep(speed,2), data = cars)
> summary(mod2)
```

The reported table for `mod1` is

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -17.5791     6.7584  -2.601   0.0123 *  
speed         3.9324     0.4155   9.464 1.49e-12 ***
---
```

and the reported table for `mod2` is

```
Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   -17.5791     4.7299  -3.717 0.000336 ***
rep(speed, 2)   3.9324     0.2908  13.523  < 2e-16 ***
---
```

As we can see, $\frac{0.4155}{\sqrt{2}} = 0.2938$, which is not equal to $0.2908$ in `mod2`'s table. Is there a reason for this difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is due to the d.f. in the denominator of the t-statistic.

The cars data has $n=50$. The d.f. in that first standard error is $48$. In the duplicated data, it's $98$. The ratio of $\sqrt{2}$ to $\sqrt{98/48}$ is $\sqrt{96/98}\approx 0.9897$ which is the factor by which the $0.4155/\sqrt{2}$ is off - about 1% - simply multiply that value by the $\sqrt{96/98}$ factor and you're right on the money. As $n$ grows this goes away.

Comment: Is the reported `Std. Error` of the output therefore different than $\sqrt{\text{Var}\left(\hat{\beta_1}\right)}$, where $\hat{\beta_1}= (X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}Y$?

Comment: No, since the estimate of  $\text{Var}\left(\hat{\beta}_1\right)$ has an n-2 denominator for this model, that is why it's like it is.